# :valid + :invalid with webfonts on forms

Tags: forms, css, webfonts

I'm using the :valid and :invalid pseudo-classes, so the users can see if the input is correct in each form. I'm able to style them with CSS, but I have yet to find a solution where I can use an iconfont on the right side of the form, to display a valid or invalid input. Anyone knows how to do this?

Also some forms should not display valid or invalid before the user starts to type (like signup email). Can I bypass that code/css and just activate it when the user starts to type in the form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could realize what you want like this:

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AvdbL/2/)

```
input {
    border: #666 1px solid;    
    padding: 0.5em;
}

label {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 8px;
}

input + i:before {
    display: none;
}

input:focus + i:before {
    display: block;
}

input:focus:invalid {
    background: red;
}

input:focus:valid {
    background: lightgreen;
}

input:focus:valid + i:before {
    content: "\f14a";
}
```

I've used the [fontawesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/) iconfont here.

**EDIT**

To make the icons inside the form elements you can add this rule:

```
input + i {
    position: relative;
    left: -20px;
}
```

Comment: If I want these icons to go inside the form, how do I then do it? Shouldnt I be able to not have such things as empty <i>? I use Entypo for fonts

Comment: @MortenHjort I made an edit to my answer. The problem is you can't use the pseudo elements `:after` and `:before` on input elements that's why you need an adjacent element to display the icon. But you can use whatever you like... e.g. a `<span>` or a `<div>`

Comment: Thanks! I did have a hard time figuring it out. Only question left is how the "email" can say an email without a top-level domain is valid?Seems really strange to me.